How to solve problem Firebase Cloud Messaging
i'm trying to send Pushnotification via Firebase Cloud Messaging to my mobile but i received the below error so can you please help in fixing this issue

public String pushNotificationFCM(ProfileDTO profileDTO, SigningTransactionDTO signingTransactionDTO) {
        FirebaseApp firebaseApp = null;
        try {
          .....
                log.info(Constants.FCM_LOG_MESSAGE + ": proxy is disabled");
                // Loading the resource file from the classpath
                Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(fcmKeyPath);

                // Creating an InputStream from the resource
                try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
                    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
                            .setServiceAccountId(fcmAccountService)
                            .build();


                    if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
                        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
                    } else {
                        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.getApps().get(0);
                    }

                    log.info("Application initialized without proxy");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error( e.getMessage());
        }

try {
            response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp).send(message);
          
        } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
            log.info(" Error " + response);
      
        }
  


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

I also face same issue, So I change my logic like this
 private String token;
 private static Date tokenExpiryTime;

     private String generateFCMToken(){
            try {
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(token) && tokenExpiryTime.after(new Date())) {
                    return token;
                } else {
                    InputStream inputStream = YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("PUT_YOUR_FIREBASE_FCM_KEY_FILE");
    
                    GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(inputStream);
                    GoogleCredential scoped = googleCred.createScoped(Collections.singleton("YOUR_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_URL"));
    
                    scoped.refreshToken();
                    token = scoped.getAccessToken();
                    tokenExpiryTime = new DateTime().plusMinutes("PUT_YOUR_PREFERABLE_TIME_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_60_MIN").toDate();
                    return token;
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

In this I am storing token generate timing with in addition some minutes, then I am checking if generating time less than current time then I am generating new token.
Hope this is work for you.
